# re-write without using set, setf or setq

Tags: loops, functional-programming, lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I need some help to re-write this function in common lisp without usin `SET`, `SETF` or `SETQ` (I can't also use loops), I hope some one can help me.
here is the code:

```
(defun apply-values (DictValues Monomial)
   (let ( (Coeff (monomial-coefficient Monomial))
          (Vars (varpowers Monomial))
          (Acc 1) )
     (mapcar (lambda(x)
               (setf Acc 
                 (* Acc (expt (cdr (assoc (varpower-symbol x) 
                                          DictValues))
                              (varpower-power x))))) 
             Vars)
     (* Coeff Acc)))
```

my problem is at the line that starts with `mapcar`.

thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: indentation, *please!*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Repeated accumulative operation over a list is known as [*reduction*](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_reduce.htm):

```
(defun apply-values (DictValues Monomial)
   (reduce #'*
      (mapcar 
         (lambda (x)
            (expt (cdr (assoc (varpower-symbol x) DictValues))
                  (varpower-power x)))
         (varpowers Monomial))
      :initial-value (monomial-coefficient Monomial)))
```

Using a higher-order function that properly fits the situation allows for the functional style, without explicitly naming the interim values. The code is clearer and less prone to errors by a human coder.

Comment: @user7337963 For another exercise, try getting rid of the intermediate mapcar.

Comment: @coredump very good suggestion! Indeed the OP should try it, and ask another question about it if they have problems with it. Hint: it's about replacing `#'*` with a custom-tailored lambda function (in sloppy pseudocode, `reduce (combining a x) (map f xs)` == `reduce (combining a (f x)) xs`). Details are in CLHS (link in the answer).